# Searching a field for the whole word, and nothing but the word

Tags: php

I have a PHP interface with a keyword search, working off a DB(MySQL) which has a Keywords field.

The way in which the keywords field is set up is as follows, it is a varchar with all the words formatted as shown below...

the, there, theyre, their, thermal etc...

if i want to just return the exact word 'the' from the search how would this be achieved?

I have tried using `'the%'` and `'%the'` in the PHP and it fails to work by not returning **all** of the rows where the keyword appears in.

is there a better (more accurate) way to go about this?

Thanks

Comment: Can you paste the exact query you have tried so far?

Comment: The title sounds very religious.

Comment: " AND keywords like '%$kword%';") "that returns the string included in any word so would return all of the examples given in the original question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to select the rows that have **exactly** the keyword `the`:

> SELECT * FROM table WHERE keyword='the'

If you want to select the rows that have the keyword `the` **anywhere** in them:

> SELECT * FROM table WHERE keyword LIKE '%the%'

If you want to select the rows that **start** with the keyword `the`:

> SELECT * FROM table WHERE keyword LIKE 'the%'

If you want to select the rows that **end** with the keyword `the`:

> SELECT * FROM table WHERE keyword LIKE '%the'

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM tablename
  WHERE fieldname REGEXP '[[:<:]]test[[:>:]]'
```

`[[:<:]]` and `[[:>:]]` are markers for word boundaries.

[MySQL Regular Expressions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html)

Answer (score 1):

if you also search for the commas, you can be sure you are getting the whole word.

```
where keywordField like '%, the, %'
   or keywordField like '%, the'
   or keywordField like 'the, %'
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe I didn't understand the question properly... but If you want all the words where 'the' appears, a LIKE '%word%' should work.

If the DB of words is HUGE MySQL may fail to retrieve some of the words, that can be solved in 2 ways...

1- get a DB that support bigger sizes (not many ppl would chose this one tho). For example SQL Server has a 'CONTAINS' function that works better than LIKE '%word%'.

2- use a external search tool that uses inverted index search. I used [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/) for a project and it works quite good. This is better if you rarely UPDATE the rows of the data you want to search from, which should be the case. 
Sphinx for example would generate a file from your MySQL table and use this file to solve the search (it's very fast), this file should be re-indexed everytime you do a insert or update on the table, making it a much better solution if you rarely update or insert new rows.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a one to many relationship going on within a column. It might be better to create a separate table for keywords with a row for each keyword and a foreign key to whatever it is you're searching on.

Doing like '%???%' is generally a bad idea because the DB can't make use of an index so it will scan the whole table. Whether this matters will depend on the size of data you're working with but its worth considering up front. The single best way to help DB performance is in the initial table design. This can be tricky to change later.